# Convert MaterialDesignColors.MaterialDesignColor to SolidColorBrush?

Tags: wpf, material-design

I am using [this MaterialDesign library](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) in my C# WPF application.

How can I programatically get the HEX color ID for example from the color `MaterialDesignColors.MaterialDesignColor.LightBlue500` and then convert it to a `SolidColorBrush`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can get any `MaterialDesignColor` using the [`SwatchHelper`](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/88e6bb5a7af1f63ba8d660665c3c2585b4c3b06c/MaterialDesignColors.Wpf/SwatchHelper.cs).

```
var lightBlue500Color = SwatchHelper.Lookup[MaterialDesignColor.LightBlue500];
```

You can also get it directly from the corresponding swatch, here [`LightBlueSwatch`](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignColors.Wpf/Recommended/LightBlueSwatch.cs).

```
var lightBlue500Color = LightBlueSwatch.LightBlue500;
```

```
var lightBlueSwatch = new LightBlueSwatch();
var lightBlue500Color = lightBlueSwatch.Lookup[MaterialDesignColor.LightBlue500];
```

From that color, you can create a `SolidColorBrush` using its constructor.

```
var lightBlue500SolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(lightBlue500Color);
```

If you need the hex color string in `#AARRGGBB` format, you can use the `ToString` method of `Color`.

```
var lightBlue500HexString= LightBlueSwatch.LightBlue500.ToString(); // = "#FF03A9F4"
```

If you need the `#RRGGBB` format, you can use a custom format string.

```
var lightBlue500Color = LightBlueSwatch.LightBlue500;
var lightBlue500HexString = string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", lightBlue500Color.R, lightBlue500Color.G, lightBlue500Color.B); // = "#03A9F4"
```

In general, if you want to create a solid color brush from a hex string, you can do this.

```
var lightBlue500Color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(#FF03A9F4);
var lightBlue500SolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(lightBlue500Color);
```

Comment: I have not been using WPF for a year and this is definitely the correct answer.
Very detailed answer. Well done.